# How to rewrite if file not found using NGINX

Tags: linux, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm using NGINX On Ubuntu server. I have this vhost:

```
server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   *.example.com;
        root          /home/nginx/vhosts/example.com/web;

        location / {
                index     index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I have to add a rule...

**If the file/dir IS NOT FOUND use index.php**

How could I change my server {} directive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You can use the try_files directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php
```

This will try to find files and directories first, and if that doesn't work, it will use index.php.

See also the [front controller](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Front_Controller_Pattern_based_packages) section on the nginx wiki.

Comment: is it better to use try_files or rewrite? (which is faster)

Comment: try_files specifically does what you want, so I say, this is better.

Comment: depending on proxy_params I usually wind up with:
224616#0: *96676 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/etc/nginx/proxy_params", client...
use:  if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}

Answer (score 6):

Ikke is correct, use try_files like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

But your PHP fastcgi location is insecure. See [this article](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/) to find out more about that.

For your setup you need to have something like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

Note that you should set local `fastcgi_param` after including the fastcgi_params global config.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fllow setting:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   *.example.com;
    root          /home/nginx/vhosts/example.com/web;

    location / {
            index     index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            root /home/nginx/vhosts/example.com/web;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

hope help you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on RH6 an EC2 and I fixed it by hard coding the `$document_root`, in the param `fastcgi_param`.
Hope it helped.