# Nginx rewrite all directory requests to index.php

Tags: redirect, nginx

Okay I'm kind of n00b on Nginx, and I've browsed through here and couldn't piece together an answer. SO here is what i got

```
server {
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html


        if (-f $request_filename) {  
            expires 30d;  
            break;  
        }  
        if (!-e $request_filename) {  
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;  
        }  
}

location /dojump {
    rewrite ^/dojump/(.*)$ /dojump/index.php/$1 break;
}


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

This is on a wordpress setup the first location block should pass all file requests to the wordpress bootstrap.

the `location /dojump` block is supposed to be for an outbound redirect script i have. I want to catch the arguments and pass them to the index.php script

like /dojump/cnn.com 
to /dojump/index.php/cnn.com

it works with apache with this simple **.htaccess** line inside the dojumps folder

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

however, I get an nginx error in the **error log**

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/dojump/index.php/cnn.com" failed (20: Not a directory)
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Lots of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920081/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255446/ Nginx has a page dedicated to Wordpress: http://wiki.nginx.org/Wordpress

Answer (score 4):

Try passing the url as a GET parameter.

```
rewrite ^/dojump/(.*)$ /dojump/index.php?url=$1 break;
```